Use python with Windev

I'm trying to run the following code in WinDev:
info(calcul(1,2))

But I have the following error:

The Python API has not been loaded.
Call stack:
Clic sur BTN_Result (WIN_calcul.BTN_Result), line 2
Project: testcalcul
Additional information:
Error code: 1230
Module: wd280vm.dll (05F280095g - 28.0.661.9 EXPRESS)


I use the "calcul.py" file which contains the function:

def calcul(a,b):
    return a+b


And I use WinDev 32bit, and python3.12 32bit, I put the link in the python interpretuer box in WinDev:


"C:\Users\Farouq MOUSMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\python312.dll"

Do you have any idea about this error please?
get 3 result of info(calcul(1,2))
